# MySQL is not working on MacOS 14 (Sonoma) from command line

Tags: macos-sonoma, mysql-cli

I have tried to install MySQL. I downloaded the community Edition of MySQL 8.2 from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and installed it. The Installation process went on smoothly but when I tried to connect to mySQL Server from command line using command
`mysql -u root -p`
I got following error
`zsh: command not found: mysql`
I also tried to run where is and which command the response is as follows
`focus@MacBook-Pro bin % which mysqld mysqld not found focus@MacBook-Pro bin % whereis mysql mysql: focus@MacBook-Pro bin % whereis mysq  mysq: focus@MacBook-Pro bin % whereis mysqld mysqld: focus@MacBook-Pro bin % whichis mysql mysql not found`

I checked my MySQL Installation (Screenshot below)
[MySQL Service is runnign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbXfP.png)

I found some blogs that says that error may be due to path settings. I even tried to run the command from `/usr/local/mysql/bin`
still no luck

Comment: You need to find where you installed the mysql command line clinet and run it from there. It will be under the bin folder where you installed mysql to. We can't tell you where you installed mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your MySQL Server is online you can try connecting with MySQL Workbeanch still if you want to use terminal and connect to MySQL on command line you will need to add the path of your MySQL Binaries which is located in /usr/local/mysql/bin to your system path run following commands on terminal

```
echo "export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now you can use terminal to connect to MySQL Server

`mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Thank you @Inder-singh-thakur I saw similar solution while setting up php